# Simple plugin architecture implementation - passing instance

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, singleton

I created a custom Usercontrol (a TextEditor) in my main library and I'm implementing a very simple plugin system extensions. A Plugin is an external library that is loaded dynamically at startup; during initialization I pass the TextEditor instance so Plugin can use it. Inside the library there can be several classes that need this instance.

My question is: where should I keep this instance? I thought about having a Singleton object in any plugin holding my common instance, or maybe have a Singleton in my main library and use this in all my plugins.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your architecture, but if I had a assembly/library with custom controls, I would reference it in the plugin, and any other assemblies that use it.  Passing an instance of a control to another assembly seems odd.  Perhaps I am missing something though

Comment: Sorry maybe my explanation was not good. Yes, I reference main library into plugin but I need an instance of that control so my plugin can works with it. For example if I have an ImagePlugin that extend my editor allowing user to choose an image and place under caret, the plugin should have an instance of editor